# Lock statement in expression-bodied property

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

So this doesn't work:

```
public int BufferedCount => { lock (buffer) { return buffer.Count; } }
```

The first `{` is unexpected. But I don't know why.

This also doesn't work:

```
public int BufferedCount => lock (buffer) { return buffer.Count; }
```

`buffer` is a private list that must be protected against parallel requests from multiple threads. The property should give the current count of that list.

I think I've seen an expression-bodied property with a `lock` statement somewhere recently but I can't figure out how it must look like.

Comment: Use a lock-object instead of the list itself

Comment: What is your question? How to solve it or why it doesn't allow this syntax?

Comment: @TimSchmelter That's only needed if the list is exposed publicly, or changes over the lifetime of the object, both of which are fairly uncommon.

Comment: The body of the property must be an expression (hence: *expression bodied property*).  You can't use a lock statement in an expression.

Comment: You can use an [expression body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) definition whenever the logic for any supported member, such as a method or property, **consists of a single expression**

Comment: Compare with this: you can't say `var x = lock(buffer) { return buffer.Count; }` either (with or without `{ }` around it). Only what would be a valid right hand side is usable as an expression body. You are confusing expression bodied property with lambda statements: those allow both braces and arbitrary code inside it.

Answer (score 6):

The `lock` statement is a *statement*, not an expression, and so it cannot be the expression of an expression bodied member.  You need to use a traditional method body syntax to have the body be a `lock` statement.

The only way to use a `lock` statement in an expression bodied member is to use some sort of expression that composes other statements, which would all be super hacky and way more work than just not using an expression bodied syntax.  You'd have to do something like defining a lambda and immediately executing it, which would involve way more boilerplate code than writing a traditional method body.